# MVC 4 Resting Textfield before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reset

I've been messing around with this code can can not seem to get it right and have not found any good info on making this work.

I need to clear a search text box and reset the view. I figured javascript to clear the text box and to submit the form would be the way to get this done but can not seem to make it work. My starter code is as follows

BUTTON CODE:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <input type="submit" id = "Reset" value ="Reset"/>
    </div>
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $("#Reset").click(function (event) {
        $("#Reset").val("");
    });
</script>
```

I would assume that I would need to do a herf in the javascript after the call to reset the textbox. Am I on the right track or is there an easier way to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with a push from UmairP and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582104/asp-net-mvc-how-to-find-exactly-which-button-was-clicked-when-button-names-are), here is the final solution:

Form submit buttons

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" id = "Search" value ="Search" />
        <input type="submit" name = "Reset" value ="Reset"/>
    </div>
}
```

Controller code:

```
var restButton = Request.Params.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(key => key.StartsWith("Reset"));
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(restButton))
{
    SearchString = "";
}
```

I can then run the rest of my code as normal with a  ModelState.Clear() to clear the form fields on postback.

Answer (score 2):

You need only one of these

1. Reset Button
2. JavaScript code

to reset text

For Reset button, try the following

```
<input type="reset" id = "Reset" value ="Reset"/>
```

Notice the `type=reset` not submit

For JavaScript, you need to assign Id to textbox and use it to empty the text.
Change textbox code to

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString",null, new {@id = "txtSearch"})
```

and JavaScript to

```
<script>
    $("#Reset").click(function (event) {
        $("#txtSearch").val("");
    });
</script>
```

BTW, You are using jQuery code but you haven't mentioned jQuery in Tag.

Comment: Must have missed the tag (it was late). The problem with the way that this is set up, this will clear if the form wasn't submitted. But in my case this is a text search so the form is submitted and the search term is posted back to the text box so the reset will not clear because it is part of the original load. I need to clear the text box and then resubmit so that the form re-posts and all database entries are listed.

Comment: In that case, you can keep the `type=submit` for your reset button and use the jQuery code to submit empty text for search

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. See my addition to post for solution. I up ticked your solution as is presents two very good ways of handling a form reset.